# Disable Sessions in Kraken or node

Tags: javascript, node.js, kraken.js

Hey everyone I need to remove Sessions in my Kraken.js project when NODE_ENV=production due to this:

```
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

Here is my Index.js file.

```
'use strict';


var kraken = require('kraken-js'),
    app = require('express')(),
    options = require('./lib/spec')(app),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8000;


app.use(kraken(options));


app.listen(port, function (err) {
    console.log('[%s] Listening on http://localhost:%d', app.settings.env, port);
});
```

here is the production.json that configures all of my prod options. This was duplicated from development.json

```
"middleware": {
        "devtools": {
            "enabled": true,
            "priority": 35,
            "module": {
                "name": "kraken-devtools",
                "arguments": [
                    "path:./public",
                    "path:./.build",
                    {   
                        "template": {
                            "module": "kraken-devtools/plugins/dustjs",
                            "files": "/templates/**/*.js",
                            "base": "templates",
                            "i18n": "config:i18n"
                        },
                        "css": {
                            "module": "kraken-devtools/plugins/less",
                            "files": "/css/**/*.css"
                        },
                        "copier": {
                            "module": "kraken-devtools/plugins/copier",
                            "files": "**/*"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"middleware": {
  "session": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "devtools": {
        "enabled": true,
        "priority": 35,
        "module": {
            "name": "kraken-devtools",
            "arguments": [
                "path:./public",
                "path:./.build",
                {   
                    "template": {
                        "module": "kraken-devtools/plugins/dustjs",
                        "files": "/templates/**/*.js",
                        "base": "templates",
                        "i18n": "config:i18n"
                    },
                    "css": {
                        "module": "kraken-devtools/plugins/less",
                        "files": "/css/**/*.css"
                    },
                    "copier": {
                        "module": "kraken-devtools/plugins/copier",
                        "files": "**/*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The relevant portion being the `"session": { "enabled": false }`.